# Unicode - Just print the string

Tags: python, python-unicode

```
print proc1
"\u001b[H\u001b[2J\r\nPRINT ME"
```

How to print only "PRINT ME". I do not want to print other chunks.

The above is an output of a shell script when Python `fabric` gives a `run` call.
I return the `fabric` message to my `Flask` as

```
return json.dumps(proc1)
```

**Update**:

The response from `flask` is as below:

```
"Output": "\"\\u001b[H\\u001b[2J\\r\\nPROCESS1       : process not running\\r\\n \\r\\nPROCESS2       : process running\\r\\nT\""}
```

I'm looking at removing `\u001b[H2J` and other junks

Comment: Given that `flask` output, what should the result be? `PROCESS1`? `PROCESS1       : ...` until the end of the string? Something else? Also, do you have any information on the `PROCESS1` string? If it is the name of a process you know then it might be possible to use a regex to find it, without trimming the start of the text.

Comment: The result should be PROCESS1 : till the end of the valid text for the user. No, I will not be aware that PROCESS1 will be the output. It might be any..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to use `str.split` and its `maxsplit` parameter:

```
In [1]: output = "\"\\u001b[H\\u001b[2J\\r\\nPROCESS1       : process not running\\r\\n \\r\\nPROCESS2       : process running\\r\\nT\""

In [2]: output.split('\\r\\n', maxsplit=1)[-1]
Out[2]: 'PROCESS1       : process not running\\r\\n \\r\\nPROCESS2       : process running\\r\\nT"'
```

If you are using an old version of python(I believe python2 and python3.x, x <= 2) you may need to specify the `maxsplit` as a positional parameter:

```
In [3]: output.split('\\r\\n', 1)[-1]
Out[3]: 'PROCESS1       : process not running\\r\\n \\r\\nPROCESS2       : process running\\r\\nT"'
```

The junk at the beginning of the output seems like an escape sequence that clears the terminal(at least, doing:

```
print "\u001b[H\u001b[2J\r\nPRINT ME".decode('unicode-escape')
```

Has this effect in the Konsole.

Assuming the format will always be `"UTUT\r\n` with `U` being a unicode escape in the form `\uxxxx` with `x` hexadecimal digits, and `T` being a terminal escape made of `[` plus digits and letters, the following should be able to strip off the first characters:

```
In [9]: regex = re.compile(r'"\\u(\d|[a-f])+\[(\w|\d)+\\u(\d|[a-f])+\[(\d|\w)+\\r\\n')

In [10]: regex.sub('', output)
Out[10]: 'PROCESS1       : process not running\\r\\n \\r\\nPROCESS2       : process running\\r\\nT"'
```

If you don't want the last `"` you can simply do:

```
regex.sub('', output)[:-1]
```

Which will simply trim the beginning of the string and remove the last character.
If for some reason the `"` may not be the last character you could use:

```
In [2]: regex = re.compile(r'"\\u(\d|[a-f])+\[(\w|\d)+\\u(\d|[a-f])+\[(\d|\w)+\\r\\n(?P<content>[^"]+)')

In [3]: output = "\"\\u001b[H\\u001b[2J\\r\\nPROCESS1       : process not running\\r\\n \\r\\nPROCESS2       : process running\\r\\nT\""

In [4]: regex.match(output).group('content')
Out[4]: 'PROCESS1       : process not running\\r\\n \\r\\nPROCESS2       : process running\\r\\nT'
```

Where I assume the string that you need does *not* contains `"`.

Comment: Can you help with your regex to remove the `"` as well

Comment: You mean the last `"`? I believe it would be easier to simply do `regex.sub('', output)[:-1]` and remove the last character with slicing. Otherwise you have to change the regex to use a group for the content in the middle, *assuming* the `PROCESS1...` string *cannot* contain the `"`.

Answer (score -1):

Python is representing the string proc1 as a byte string. Make sure it's represented as a unicode string, prefix the string with a u.

So,

```
proc1 = u"\u001b[H\u001b[2J\r\nPRINT ME"
```